# How to authenticate Squid against a custom backend?

Tags: authentication, squid

I want to setup a proxy service using squid and want it to authenticate against a database or another service.

There is an example config at http://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Authenticate/Mysql

```
auth_param basic program /usr/local/squid/libexec/squid_db_auth --user someuser --password xxxx --plaintext --persist
auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Web-Proxy
auth_param basic credentialsttl 1 minute
auth_param basic casesensitive off


acl db-auth proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow db-auth
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all
```

the relevant snippet appears to be

```
auth_param basic program /usr/local/squid/libexec/squid_db_auth --user someuser --password xxxx --plaintext --persist
```

Do I have to replace *someuser* with actual username and *xxxx* with password?

For each user I add, do I have to add it to this config?

Ideally, I want a setup whereby, I am able to add/remove users to the service without changing the config file. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`--user someuser` and `--password xxxx` are the username and password used to authenticate against the MySQL database. The proxy users must be created in the table `passwd` inside the `squid` database.

For reference: [squid_db_auth manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/squid3_db_auth.8.html), [how to build squid authentication helpers](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/authentication_with_squid).

Comment: thanks. I didn't realize that squid_db_auth was actually a program. It makes assumptions about db name and table names, which was throwing me off.  Its man page (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/squid3_db_auth.8.html) helps. Also - a post http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/authentication_with_squid helps in figuring out what is exactly required of such a helper.